# FreeRDP Security Negotiation Failure

Tags: freerdp

When I Try to connect from Ubuntu with FreeRDP to Windows 2008 R2 with NLA:

```
[14:29:31:523] [1146:-1236755648] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - connect
[14:29:31:523] [1146:-1236755648] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Protocol Security Negotiation Failure
[14:29:31:523] [1146:-1236755648] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error 0x2000C
[14:29:31:523] [1146:-1236755648] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140371/44760

Comment: No, I  don't use TGW and I want not input password second when connect to Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else experiencing this, it occurs because Network Level Authentication is enabled on the Windows host.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I resolved it by using the following on the Command Line:

```
xfreerdp /sec:rdp /u:fake.user /v:fake.host.com
```